# How can I split a long string in source code into several lines for more readability in C++?

Tags: c++, string, string-concatenation, string-literals, multilinestring

In other word how to make my code working if I don't want to write it one line?

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string menu = "";
    menu += "MENU:\n"
        + "1. option 1\n"
        + "2. option 2\n"
        + "3. option 3\n"
        + "4. 10 more options\n";
}
```

Comment: Did you try just getting rid of the `+`s?

Comment: Yeah, nothing would be changed

Comment: "1. option 1\n" underlined red, and when I hover it it says expression must have integral or uscoped enum type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply remove the `+`'s:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string menu = "MENU:\n"
        "1. option 1\n"
        "2. option 2\n"
        "3. option 3\n"
        "4. 10 more options\n";
}
```

Adjacent string literals are [automatically concatenated by the compiler](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

Alternatively, in C++11, you can use raw string literals, which preserve all indentation and newlines:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string menu = R"(MENU:
1. option 1
2. option 2
3. option 3
4. 10 more options
)";

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `+`s. By just leaving those out, the compiler will concatenate all the string literals into one long string:

```
menu += "MENU:\n"
    "1. option 1\n"
    "2. option 2\n"
    "3. option 3\n"
    "4. 10 more options\n";
```

Comment: To clarify, the compiler will concatenate any two consecutive strings, e.g. `"a" "b"` into `"ab"`.

Comment: @IlCapitano Reworded a bit

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the add operators in your example. Consecutive strings with nothing between them are simply concatenated. So, for example, the two consecutive tokens `"hello " "world"` is the same as `"hello world"`. But keep in mind that source code line breaks can separate any two tokens, so `"hello "` and `"world"` can be on separate lines, just as you wish.

Comment: may be you omitted 'not' particle after word 'can' in last sentance?

Comment: @Denis_newbie — no, the last sentence is correct. They can be on separate lines.